# How can I add multiple backgrounds to a single webpage?

Tags: html

How can I add multiple backgrounds to a single webpage? I mean different backgrounds in different sections.

Comment: Do you want them behind divs, or just tiled around.  Easiest way I can think of is photoshop a tiled background, then just use that.

Answer (score 1):

Just divide those sections by for example `<div>`.

```
<div id="section1"></div>
<div id="section2"></div>
<div id="section3"></div>
```

Then use the [CSS `background-image` property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) on each of them.

```
#section1 { 
    background-image: url('images/section1.png');
}
#section2 { 
    background-image: url('images/section2.png');
}
#section3 { 
    background-image: url('images/section3.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `<div>`s to section out your webpage, you can use the `background` CSS property to specify different backgrounds per section. [Quick tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).

Answer (score 0):

and if you don't care about explorer (oh, how nice that would be), you [could use multiple background on one div (CSS3)](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html#multiple).