# Background to a form

Tags: html, css, forms

How to have a background to a form and have different image for whole page back ground in html.

Comment: added tags: CSS, Forms and Form :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add multiple backgrounds to a single webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199026/how-can-i-add-multiple-backgrounds-to-a-single-webpage)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with css.

Place the following into the `<head>` of your HTML document:

```
<style>
    body{background:url(/path/to/your/body/image.jpg);}
    form{background:url(/path/to/your/form/image.jpg);}
</style>
```

You could also have these styles defined directly on the html tags, like this:

```
<body style="background:url(path/to/your/body/image/jpg);">
```

and

```
<form style="background:url(path/to/your/form/image/jpg);" method="post" action="your action">
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I wouldn't go for the inline style declaration. It's better to keep CSS seperate from your HTML (also if you plan on caching your CSS file)

Answer (score 2):

In your external css file:

```
body {
  background: url('body_bg.jpg');
}

form {
  background: url('form_bg.jpg');
}
```

include your external css file like this:

```
<head>
  <link rel=stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css" media=screen />
</head>
```